# How to take a picture on a mobile and upload it using the Node-RED Dashboard nodes

Tags: node-red

I have Node-RED running in a cloud. Now I'd like to

- click on a Dashboard button
- have a pop-up window asking if the user wants to either take a picture or use an existing one from the library
- upload the picture to Node-RED

Would appreciate any advise or example flow.

Comment: What have you already tried? We'll help you fix something but just write it for you.

Comment: found a way meanwhile, using the ui_template node, thx: <form action="/upload_web" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Take New Image" name="submit">
</form>

Comment: Please post a real answer, comments do not do code well (you can also accept your own answer making it easier for others to find)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the ui_template node:

```
<form action="/upload_web" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Take New Image" name="submit"> 
</form>
```